# Rewriting Integral for Cauchy's Integral Formula to be applied

Tags: complex-analysis

Been stuck on this question for a few days and I really need some help please!

Here is the question:

$$\int_C \frac {\overline z}{ z - a} \,dz$$
where the contour $C$ is the unit circle $|z| = 1$ mapped counter-clockwise and $a$ is a constant.

Rewrite this into a form for which Cauchy's Integral Formula can be applied, and then evaluate it.

Can anyone help with this please? Would be much appreciated. I'm alright at using Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate it's just rewriting this which is proving difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: on the unit circle $z \overline{z} = 1$.

Comment: The answer should depend on whether $a$ is inside or outside the contour.

Comment: so if |a|>1 we have I = -i2pi and if |a|<1 we have I=0 as it's not inside the contour?